# Cannot get access token from API

Tags: ios, swift, http

[image]

I'm new to Swift and I just faced a problem. Any help and suggestion is welcome, also I've seen Alomofire, but I was not able to setup Alamofire because of some errors, and also I need help in Alamofire :|

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:   
      "Accept")
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
      forHTTPHeaderField:   "Content-Type")
    let postString = ["grant_type"  : "password" ,
                      "username"    : EntPhoneNumber.text! ,
                      "password"    : EntPassword.text! ,] as [String : 
 Any]
    do {
        
        
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: 
 postString)
    }catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        DisplayMessage(UserMessage: "Something went wrong , please try 
 again!")
        return
    }
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
    {
        (data : Data? , response : URLResponse? , error : Error?) in
        
        self.removeActivtyIndicator(activityIndicator: 
 MyActivityIndicator)
        
        
        
        if error != nil
        {
            self.DisplayMessage(UserMessage: "1Could not successfully 
 perform this request , please try again later.")
            print("error = \(String(describing : error))")
            return
        }
        
        
        
        // let's convert response sent from a server side code to a 
 NSDictionary object:
        
        do { let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, 
 options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            
            print(json!)
            if let parseJSON = json
            {
                let userID = parseJSON["grant_type"] as? String
                print("access_token : \(String(describing: userID))");
                
                if userID == nil
                {
                    //display an alert dialog with a friendly error 
message
                    self.DisplayMessage(UserMessage: "2Could not 
successfully perform this request , please try later.")
                    return
                }
                else
                {
                    self.DisplayMessage(UserMessage: "3successfully 
loged in.")
                }
            }
```

...

As you can see this is my code which I'm posting a request to API to get an `access_token` but I receive an error:

> {error = "invalid_request";
> "error_description" = "The mandatory 'grant_type' parameter is missing.";
> }

These are the parameters that I should post to API and in postman it works properly but my code does not work at all in compiler.

[image]

Comment: Add url you are trying to post?

Comment: @ChanWarde   let myUrl = URL(string: "http://api.nahadeh.com/connect/token")

Comment: To add Alamofire to your project, you need to use CocoaPods, https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#installation.

Comment: so... where did you set the `Content Length` in the header? because I see that part nowhere.

Comment: @holex i didn't set content-lenght in postman but it worked

Comment: because Postman sets that value for you automatically... but the standard networking in iOS does not... that was a _hint_ for you that you must set that value in the header explicitly in your iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

you are making it too complex

```
let postString = ["grant_type"  : "password" ,
                      "username"    : EntPhoneNumber.text! ,
                      "password"    : EntPassword.text! ,] as [String :
                        Any]

    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: postString, encoding: URLEncoding.methodDependent, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in

        if let json = response.result.value {
            print("Response: ",json)
        }

    }
```

try this.

This is all you need. If you have any doubt ask here.

Comment: I really like to use Alamofire , but i don't know how to add it to my project! could you how to add alamofire

Comment: use cocoa pods or simply drag and drop framework in your project

Comment: also i have to use this " request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:   "Content-Type")"    header must be this

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link to install Alamofire using CocoaPods

https://www.raywenderlich.com/156971/cocoapods-tutorial-swift-getting-started[enter link description here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/156971/cocoapods-tutorial-swift-getting-started)

I have created this custom method for API request.

```
func request(_ method: HTTPMethod
    , _ URLString: String
    , parameters: [String : AnyObject]? = [:]
    , headers: [String : String]? = [:]
    , completion:@escaping (Any?) -> Void
    , failure: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

    Alamofire.request(URLString, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                completion(response.result.value!)
            case .failure(let error):
                failure(error)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed the link and installed and it added pods_<appname>.framework and still can't add alamofire!!!!

Comment: I opened my project in the welcome page :| :), i'm so confused in Swift :|

Comment: What welcome page? I am asking you did you open .xcodeProj file or .xcworkspcae file. Go to folder where your project located

Comment: Listen when you install any library with pod, then you must have to open .xcworkspace file instead of .xcodeproje. From now open .xcwprkspace which will be in same directory

Comment: It doesn't work in .xcworkspace too! frameworks are red as they should be black!!

Comment: as you said , i opened .xcworkspace , but the framework is red and i can't import it to code

Comment: What error you getting? please post it. Red color doesnt matter

Comment: i uploaded a photo .

Comment: Where did you upload? You are doing something wrong.

Comment: in the first line of this post in my question somewhere is saying enter image description

Comment: Ok. Try by adding Alamofire in Project -> General -> Embeded Bineries as well as in Linked Framework and Libraries

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the login and password parameters in query while sending the request. Lets create a separate `Network` class which has `loginRequest(username:password)` function which makes the API request to the server with username and password params. The login method has a `closure` which either returns a userId string or Error.

```
class Networking {

    enum NetworkError: Error {
        case parsingData
        case jsonParsing
        case emptyData
        case apiError(error: Error)
    }

    func parseJSON(from data: Data) throws -> Any {
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
            return json
        } catch {
            return error
        }
    }

    func loginRequest(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (String?, NetworkError?) -> ()) {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "api.nahadeh.com/connect/token")!)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let queryParams = "grant_type=password&username=\(username)&password=\(password)"
        request.httpBody = queryParams.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            guard error != nil else {
                completion(nil, NetworkError.apiError(error: error!))
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                return completion(nil, NetworkError.emptyData)
            }

            do {
                let json = try self.parseJSON(from: data) as! [String: Any]
                guard let accessToken = json["access_token"] as? String else {
                    completion(nil, NetworkError.jsonParsing)
                    return
                }
                completion(accessToken, nil)
            } catch {
                completion(nil, NetworkError.jsonParsing)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Now from your UIViewController subclass you can create the instance of Networking class and call the login method with username and password params

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    let networking = Networking()

    func login(username: String, password: String) {

        networking.loginRequest(username: username, password: password) { (token, error) in

            if let token = token {
                print(token)
                self.displayMessage("Successfully loged in. Go to home screen")
                return
            }

            if let nError = error {
                switch nError {
                case .jsonParsing:
                    self.displayMessage("jsonParsingError")
                case .emptyData:
                    self.displayMessage("emptyData")
                case .apiError(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    self.displayMessage("Could not successfully perform this request , please try later.")
                case .parsingData:
                    self.displayMessage("parsingData")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func displayMessage(_ message: String, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Message", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire) it's very easy to make API request, just pass the params and it will do the work for you

```
  func loginRequest(username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> ()) {

        let params: [String: String] = [
            "grant_id": "password",
            "username": username,
            "password" : password
        ]

        Alamofire.request("api.nahadeh.com/connect/token", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: .httpBody, headers: nil).validate().response { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let accessToken = value["access_token"]
                completion(accessToken, nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should i add this code you sent to my code , or change it with this?

Comment: You can add this code for clarity or replace relevant part to check if it works.

Comment: i changed my code with your, now how should i call these func?

Comment: just copy paste the login function from LoginViewController in your ViewController and call login(username: "username", password: "password") method from viewDidLoad method

Comment: I think this method should work but i'm a bit confused with the func and classes , could u sort them totally and send them again pls?

Comment: not sure what you want, I suggest you to spend some time learning basics of iOS before moving on to networking and other stuff. Here is the great resource https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read and https://www.raywenderlich.com/category/swift. To solve your problem just add queryParams and request.httpBody lines to your function.

Comment: thanks for your resources , and one more question , (username: EntPhoneNumber.text!, password: EntPassword.text!, completion: , completion: )     what should I set in both COMPLETION ?

Comment: it's a closure, check the login method from LoginViewController and use it